# want to convert string mm/dd/yy to date yyyy/mm/dd format in Sybase

Tags: sql, sap-ase, sap-iq, isql

I want to convert date which is string and like mm/dd/yy to date datatype in format yyyy/mm/dd.

Comment: have you tried something? basically you will have to parse the string to a date using the first format a format to it back to a string using the second format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set date format in sybase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013037/how-to-set-date-format-in-sybase)

Comment: I tried using convert(char(10),'mm/dd/yy',101) but getting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would double cast it, once to `datetime`, then back to `varchar`.

```
select convert(varchar,convert(datetime,'12/14/2012'),101)
```

This works on SQL Server, but I don't have a Sybase instance to test on.

Edit:  Looks like you could also use this:

```
select convert(varchar,date('12/14/2012'),101)
```

Comment: Thanks. First query worked for me. But What will be the syntax for date is like 00/00/00. Above logic is not working for this.

Comment: Getting error as "Arithmetic overflow during explicit conversion of CHAR value '00/00/00' to a DATETIME field ."

Comment: @RDP If your date strings don't represent valid dates, type conversion can't fix that.  I would use the `ISDATE()` function in your where clause to filter out invalid dates.  You'll have to fix those some other way. http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1260/html/iqref/Isdate_misc_functions.htm

Answer (score 0):

You have to first add a date field to your table:

```
alter table *your_table* add *newdate* as date;
```

Then you can convert using:

```
update *your_table* set *newdate* = cast(*your_string_date* as date);
```